# Disable the repetition feature of a particular keyboard key

Tags: keyboard

Is it possible on Windows 7 to disable the repetition feature of a particular keyboard key?

I'm asking this because I assigned a few keys to some mouse side buttons that keep typing although I release them with my finger, and I still need the repeating function on my keyboard, at least for some keys like the four arrows (up, down, left, right)

Comment: No, not possible. It's all or none.

Comment: How about with some deep programmation modification?